# winrm quickconfig fails on windows 10 with error 500 0x1F4. variable not defined

Tags: windows, powershell-remoting

on a windows 10 machine (22h2, up to date) I want to enable ps remoting, but loading the default configuration seems broken. A variable seems to be missing. Unfortunately I have no clue how to fix this. There are almost no search results for this specific problem.

**winrm quickconfig**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm quickconfig
Der WinRM-Dienst wird auf diesem Computer bereits ausgeführt.

Fehlernummer:  500 0x1F4
Variable ist nicht definiert
```

**enable-psremoting**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> enable-psremoting -force
WinRM ist bereits zum Empfangen von Anforderungen auf diesem Computer konfiguriert.
Set-WSManQuickConfig : Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.
Parametername: s
In Zeile:116 Zeichen:17
+                 Set-WSManQuickConfig -force
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-WSManQuickConfig], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentNullException,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.SetWSManQuickConfigCommand
```

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.2673
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2673
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I have tried to run `winrm quickconfig` and `enable-psremoting` from an elevated shell. UAC is active. The user is a local administrator. Both commands fail. I think it fails somewhere near creating a http-listener. Some essential information must be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Using an unattend.xml for the second time (1st time in the image, 2nd time after integrating vmwaretools and drivers) destroys something within win10. With this knowledge I was able to get around the problem.